# How do I add a match in two-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript

I have a function for finding identical numbers:

```
var arr = [0, 0, 4, 8, 8, 10, 45, 0, 23, 3 ,8];
arr.filter(function (item, index, array) {    
    return array.indexOf(item) !== array.lastIndexOf(item); // [0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 8]
});
```

But, I need to create two-dimensional array for the individual matches.

So, the result should be: `[[0, 0, 0], [8, 8, 8]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
uniqueCount =[0, 0, 4, 8, 8, 10, 45, 0, 23, 3 ,8];

var  count = {}; 
var twoDimArray = [];
uniqueCount.forEach(function(i) { count[i] = (count[i]||0)+1;  });
for(key in count){
    var array = [];
    for (i=0; i<count[key]; i++){
        array.push(key);
    }
    twoDimArray.push(array);
}
alert(twoDimArray);
//alert(JSON.stringify(count));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ahmada4/1/)**